# MS Access's user interface to interact with data from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, odbc

On `Windows 7`, I must connect a MS Access client `.accdb`, where all the forms, `VBA` scripts, macro, and reports are, to a `MySQL Database` instead of a MS Access database `.mdb`. Here what I have tried so far.
I created a connection with `MySQL Connector /ODBC 5.3 Unicode` [driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html) to the `MySQL` database with success.
After in MS Access 2013, I created a new database `.mdb` by linking to my local machine `ODBC` Connector. I can see the data in each table I have linked.

However, I didn’t find where to change the connection’s setup of the MS Access client `.accdb` so it uses the data from the new `.mdb` file linked to the MySQL database. Where do we do that?

Actually, I had also tried to directly connect the .accdb to MySQL by linking to my local machine ODBC Connector. In that case, the .accdb's forms kept trying to connect to the previous .mdb database. Where can I change this configuration?

Is there another, maybe easier way to use MS Access's user interface to interact with data from a `MySQL database`?

Comment: Why not connect the .accdb to MySQL skipping out the middle man, .mdb?

Comment: Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=67709

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that I had already tried to link the .accdb to MySQL by linking to my local machine ODBC Connector. In that case, the .accdb's forms kept trying to connect to the previous .mdb database. Where can I change this configuration?
The MySQL database is the converted .mdb database. All the tables and their fields are the same.
In the forms and the report, the record sources are as previously. However, the accdb still try to open and access the .mdb database for some reason. Can it be a cached data in memory? Thanks again!

Comment: Different platforms, different people... Is there a problem in posting our question on different forums? If it's the case, I'm sorry, I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look into the [MySQL-Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) on external mysql tables

Comment: Hi, I have redone all the procedure to connect the Access UI .accdb to the MySQL database via connector ODBC. It didn't work before I restarted Access. After, it worked... Maybe there is a cached activated on my Access's system? Thanks for your help!